# Functions: how to use columns as parameters?

Tags: python, pandas

I would need to create a new column with data extracted from another column.

```
Name Surname Age
Nivea Jones   45
Kelly Pams    68
Matthew Currigan 24
...
```

I would like to create a new column with only the first letter from the name and surname, i.e.

```
Name Surname Age  Short FN
Nivea Jones   45    NJ
Kelly Pams    68    KP
Matthew Currigan 24 MC
...
```

I did as follows:

```
 df['Short FN'] = df['Name'].str.get(0) +df['Surname'].str.get(0)
```

and it works well. However, I would need to build a function, with two columns (in this case, name and surname) as parameters:

```
def sh(x,y): 
  df['Short FN'] = df[x].str.get(0) +df[y].str.get(0)
return
```

and it does not work, probably because I should keep in mind that I am using columns from a dataframe as parameter. Also, I do not know if and what I should return.

Could you please explain me how to create a function where I check/pass columns and how to use this function (not clear to me if I need to iterate through rows using a for loop)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def sh(x, y): 
     return x[0] + y[0]

df['Short'] = df.apply(lambda x: sh(x['Name'], x['Surname']), axis=1)
print(df)

      Name   Surname  Age Short
0    Nivea     Jones   45    NJ
1    Kelly      Pams   68    KP
2  Matthew  Currigan   24    MC
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that. The simplest way, assuming `df` is global (as it seems to be in your case), is:

```
def short_name(col1, col2):
    return df[col1].str[0] + df[col2].str[0]
```

calling `short_name("Name", "Surname")`

produces:

```
0    NJ
1    KP
2    MC
dtype: object
```

You can now use it in whatever way you want. For example:

```
df["sn"] = short_name("Name", "Surname")
print(df)

# produces: 
      Name   Surname  Age  sn
0    Nivea     Jones   45  NJ
1    Kelly      Pams   68  KP
2  Matthew  Currigan   24  MC
```